# RxLib for Delphi 10.4 with FireDAC?

Tags: delphi, migration, legacy, firedac, bde

I wish to migrate a huge Delphi 5 code using RXlib BDE Data-Aware controls to latest Delphi 10.4 Sydney with FireDAC. I wonder if there anywhere someone who already went through it and migrated RXlib version using BDE to FireDAC?

Comment: RxLib ended up in the JEDI Visual Component Library and they also have a file to help convert to newer component names (RxLib.dat). Another source is http://www.micrel.cz/RxLib/  For BDE to Firedac start with the help : http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Migrating_BDE_Applications_to_FireDAC